# Skrollr js not scrolling down in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, skrollr

I have a problem in Skrollr js. Its working great in web browser .Also in mobile. But the problem is when I tap on a menu or scroll down arrow its not scrolling. Please help.[Link](http://demo.mejorainfotech.com/dev/twig/)
Thanks your your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a peak at your scripts, and adding anchor scroll and other html and body animating functions on anchor click will stop skrollr.menu.js from functioning.

It's best to let only this script to control all anchor scrolling.  (example - like starting at line 153-166 in your app.js file). Remove functions things like these and it should work.

Also, it may not specify clearly, but skrollr.menu.js will perform an animated scroll while not detecting a mobile browser as well, so no need to double up on code.

EDIT: I see you put it's solved and marked correct but it still doesn't work on mobile. skrollr.menu does solve it, when other scripts don't interfere. Try what I suggested and see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its solved by using skrollr-menu.